# NHibernate:HQL: Remove time part from date field

Tags: nhibernate, datetime, hql

I'm trying to group table values by date, and this HQL query works fine:

```
 SELECT  af.SubmitedDate, COUNT (af.Id) 
 FROM ApplicationForm af 
 GROUP BY af.SubmitedDate
```

The problem is that field af.SubmitedDate also contains time part, sine I'm using SQL Server 2005, so the grouping is done by date-time, not only by date.
When I try to do something like this in HQL:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), af.SubmitedDate, 105), COUNT (af.Id)
FROM ApplicationForm af 
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), af.SubmitedDate, 105)
```

...I receive this error:

```
NHibernate.QueryException was unhandled by user code
Message="undefined alias or unknown mapping: CONVERT
```

This query is correct in TSQL and I even read somewhere that CONVERT can be used, 
but I read it on Java's Hibernate forum.

So, how can I remove time part from this date, so that grouping works correct ?

Thanks in advance,
Dejan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a Scalar-Valued function inside the SQL Server 2005, which encapsulates
this command:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), af.SubmitedDate, 105)
```

And inside the XML definition I placed this:

```
<property name='SubmitedDateWithoutTime' formula='dbo.RemoveTimeFromDateTime(SubmitedDate)'/>
```

So, my HQL query looks at the end like this:

```
SELECT  af.SubmitedDateWithoutTime, COUNT (af.Id) 
FROM ApplicationForm af 
GROUP BY af.SubmitedDateWithoutTime
```

and this works flawlessly.

Answer (score 3):

You could use one of the built in functions in hql see [mssql2000dialect](https://nhcontrib.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Dialect/MsSql2000Dialect.cs)

In your case Date seems to be the one

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using MS SQL 2005 dialect, but can you please write an example how can I use this, since, I'm newbie on this one. Thanks.

Comment: The reason why I asked for this is because I'm guessing that I can apply built in function AFTER I get the result from DB,or on some value that I will PASS to HQL query, which is not what I need here.
I need to remove time part from date field, WHILE the GROUP BY is performed,so that my final outcome is records grouped by date only, not date-time.